# RemoteException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IncludeDFSN'

Tags: windows, server, admin, wac

I am trying to use Windows Admin Center's Storage migration Service to transfer data from a share drive server, to a new 2019 server. I have connected my new server to Windows Admin Center and connected to it, downloaded Storage Migration services, and I start the process. When I get to Enter credentials for the devices you want to migrate, I put in my Active directory admin account information, and hit next and get the error: RemoteException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IncludeDFSN'. I have downloaded DFS and DFS management on the server.

Answer (score 0):

See the following known issues;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-migration-service/known-issues

To resolve, update the Storage Migration Service extension to at least version 1.113.0 in Windows Admin Center. The update should automatically appear in the feed and prompt for installation.